# how to close an application in android

Tags: 2.1-eclair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the right way to close apps in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-is-the-right-way-to-close-apps-in-android)

Is there any proper way as suggested by google or android official documentation to close an application in android with out using any task killer tools ....

I ask this question as a android use not as developer.....

Answer (score 3):

Android keeps closed applications on memory as long as possible so that when you return to the application it will still be on memory and will load faster than loading from the internal memory or SD card; but if another applications needs memory, unused applications and background applications will be automatically force killed to give way to the foreground activity.

In short, Android is not Windows, don't treat them the same.

You should only force close misbehaving applications, not for freeing memory; without a dedicated task killer, you can do this from `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > *name of application* > Force Stop`

Comment: Does this consume more battery power ......

Comment: @prassee: No, applications that simply sleeps in the background does not consume more battery or use any CPU; however some applications that runs ongoing services (IM, Mails, etc) do need to wake up from time to time.

Answer (score -1):

in your application home/first/main page, press your back key/soft-key/icon.

this is the only common way for closing applications not suspending it.

Comment: But that is **not** closing the application, it's still running in the background.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Jonas .... But I have used some application in which the application closes when we double-press back key/soft-key/icon...