# What happens when the Home button on Android phone is pressed?

Tags: battery, task-management, home-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to a running program when “home” button is pressed in Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15701/what-happens-to-a-running-program-when-home-button-is-pressed-in-android-phone)

My friend raised a concern that pressing the home button is not advisable and it drains battery.

Is it true? What happens when the Home button is pressed?