# How to exit from an application which doesn’t exit on press back button?

Tags: task-management, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I am using Maverick application for GPS navigation. In previous versions the <kbd>back</kbd> button caused to quit the application. (Which is also correct behavior according to question:  [What is the right way to close apps in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-is-the-right-way-to-close-apps-in-android))
Currently I have **Maverick 1.94** Lite. When I press the <kbd>back</kbd> button, Maverick only hides to background. (The same as if I pressed <kbd>home</kbd> button). I don't see anywhere in menu an option to exit.
I wish to avoid task killers, or switching of my phone in order to quit Maverick.

How do I **exit** from Maverick?

My phone is SK17i aka Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to `Settings -> Apps` and scroll to Maverick and select it there should be a 'Force stop' button. It's not really 'exiting' as such but it will definitely force the app to totally close down and stop running in the background.