# Make apps force close automatically without going into settings

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running)

I have an HTC Desire and I have been trying to figure out how to always get my apps and things I don't use to force close when I close them with the home button.

I have tried pressing the back button until it closed but that does not work as when I go into my app killer it shows that it is still running. Also, when I go in Applications --> Manage --> Running Service, some apps are still open. In addition, the app killer isnt properly working as when I close all apps in the app killer then go into the running services, some of the apps it killed are still shown as open.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Possibly related: [What is the right way to close apps in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/927)

Comment: are you running a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod?

Comment: See the last paragraph and quote block in the "Manually Killing Apps" section of the linked duplicate.